# Snowflake Timeout Parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout

I have an engine that sends queries to snowflake through various APIs.

I've used the `STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` to set a timeout on individual queries but sometimes it will send multiple queries in succession from one API call. I need a way to set the overall timeout for those queries to be a certain amount as opposed to an individual one, does anyone know a way I can do this?

I also don't want this to be the case for all sessions, just for through this specific warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to set a cumulative timeout for a group of statements - at least not by setting some parameter in Snowflake.

It might be possible to do it by building logic into your engine